# Unable to use threadsafe in Google AppEngine project

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to set up an AppEngine service locally.  Everything compiles, but when i try to run the project, I get this error:

> SEVERE: Received exception processing C:\Users\eazyigz\Google Drive\Books\Android eBooks\Apress Practical Android Projects\PracticalAndroidProjectsSourceCode\Projects\08_GameService\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: appengine-web.xml does not contain a  element.
>   See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests for more information.
>   You probably want to enable concurrent requests.
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:79)
>       at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:130)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.loadAppEngineWebXml(AbstractContainerService.java:334)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.initContext(JettyContainerService.java:160)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:227)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
>       at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)

When I do enable **threadsafe**, Eclipse shows this compilation error:
[image]

I simply don't understand what is happening.  Can somebody shed some light?

Thank you,
Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `<threadsafe>` into `appengine-web.xml` file, not `web.xml`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add true to the file "appengine-web.xml" instead of the "web.xml"

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests